# sailsJs for admin frontend layout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I am developing a web application using sails. In this application two different type of user will be there i.e. admin and customer. So we need different layout and lots of routes. I need some basic understanding.

1. Is there any concept of group routing and route prefix? Like if my front end URL is  'www.abc.com/...' and admin URL is 'www.abc.com/admin/...'  then what will be the code for route.js. I know it is possible by hard coding each route but i want this like

for frontend

```
'/about': {
        controller : 'aboutController',
        action     : 'index'
      },
'/contact': {
        controller : 'contactController',
        action     : 'index'
      }
```

for admin

```
  'admin':{
      '/report': {
        controller : 'ReportController',
        action     : 'loadform'
      },
     '/setting': {
        controller : 'settingController',
        action     : 'index'
      }

    }
```

2.How to maintain nested folders in controllers. Like

[image]

3. any other suggestions for these kind of big applications ?